# Which Window privilege is needed for the `runas` command?

Tags: windows, privileges, runas

I have a local Windows account and I want to make it impossible to login to the machine as this user – both locally and using remote desktop. Now I have set these two "deny" privileges for the account:

1. Deny log on locally
2. Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services

I still want to use the user for running commands using `runas`. But when I now run a `runas` command I get:

```
C:\Users\user1>runas /USER:user2 cmd
Enter the password for user2:
Attempting to start cmd as user "MACHINE\user2" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - cmd
1385: Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.
```

Is there a privileges I can assign to `user2` to fix this problem?

Comment: Yeah;  You would need to allow the privileges you revoked.  The error message is pretty explicit on the reason its failing.

Comment: Does it work if you do a runas with the /noprofile switch?

Comment: how about a good password on that user account.

Comment: @Ramhound Explicit would be to mention the missing privilege, which the error message does not.

Comment: @Syberdoor I already tried that and unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: @Moab That's an alternative but what if you have a corporate policy that passwords needs to be changed every 3 months for _all_ your service accounts on _all_ machines? Therefore, I would like a solution where you cannot do an interactive login. (On UNIX/Linux you would set the login shell to `/bin/false` and/or use `sudo`.)

Comment: From what I found in short research I think the problem might be that if you make your account a service account then runas is prevented as well. This would make sense to me as with runas + sufficient tricks you can basically get a working explorer shell anyway so where would the difference be between logging in that account or running each and every program from another user session but with the rights of the account? If you have sufficient programming skill you can make a service (without gui I think) that accepts inputs from a program in another users context as workaround afaik.

Comment: try a combination of running runas with `/noprofile` switch, and adding that user to Batch Logon. Can do latter with this command : `net localgroup "Srv_SeBatchLogonRight" user2 /add`